# Angular 8, How can I create a reactive from where when one dropdown is selected another gets selected?

Tags: angular, forms, bootstrap-4, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

New to angular. I am trying to create a reactive form where when I select one value in a drop down another value in another dropdown is populated.

This is what I have so far. Any help much appriciated.

This si the object stucture I am working from.

```
{
"content": [
    {
        "name": "Furniture",
        "types": [
            {
                "name": "Shelving",
                "state": [
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "kgs",
                    "units"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "MDP",
                    "Oak",
                    "Pine",
                    "Other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Tables",
                "state": [
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "Units"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "MDP",
                    "Oak",
                    "Pine",
                    "Other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Drawers",
                "state": [
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "units"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "MDP",
                    "Oak",
                    "Pine",
                    "Other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Cupboard",
                "state": [
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "units"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "MDP",
                    "Oak",
                    "Pine",
                    "Other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Desks",
                "state": [
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "units"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "MDP",
                    "Oak",
                    "Pine",
                    "Other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Doors",
                "state": [
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "units"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "MDP",
                    "Oak",
                    "Pine",
                    "Other"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Glass",
        "types": [
            {
                "name": "Bottles",
                "state": [
                    "crushed",
                    "fragmented",
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [],
                "repeat": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Plastics",
        "types": [
            {
                "name": "PP",
                "state": [
                    "bailed",
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "kgs"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "black",
                    "transparent",
                    "other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "PVC",
                "state": [
                    "bailed",
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "kgs"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "black",
                    "transparent",
                    "other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "HDPE",
                "state": [
                    "bailed",
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "kgs"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "black",
                    "transparent",
                    "other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "PTE",
                "state": [
                    "bailed",
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "kgs"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "black",
                    "transparent",
                    "other"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "LDPE",
                "state": [
                    "bailed",
                    "loose"
                ],
                "units": [
                    "kgs"
                ],
                "repeat": [
                    "black",
                    "transparent",
                    "other"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

}

This is my reactive form as it stand but I cant seem to wrap my head around how to go about creating this.

```
<form [formGroup]="findResourcesForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">

          <div class="resources-group" formGroupName="resources">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Resources</label>
                  <select class="form-control" (change)="onResourcesChange($event)" formControlName="resourceNames">
                    <option value="" disabled>Select a Resource</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let res of catagories" [ngValue]="res">{{res.name}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Resources Type</label>
                  <select class="form-control" formControlName="resourceTypes">
                    <option value=""></option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end resources and resource types -->

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Resources Subtype</label>
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="resourceTypesName">
                <option value=""></option>
              </select>
            </div>





        </form>
```

The backing component

```
errorMessage = '';

catagories: any[];

findResourcesForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private dataInfoService: DataInfo, public fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.getAllCatagories();

this.findResourcesForm = this.fb.group({
  resources: this.fb.group({
    resourceNames: ['', [Validators.required]],
    resourceTypes: ['', [Validators.required]],
    resourceTypesName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    resourceTypesState: ['', [Validators.required]],
    resourceTypesUnits: ['', [Validators.required]],
    resourceTypesUnitsValue: ['', [Validators.required]],
    resourceTypesRepeat: ['', [Validators.required]]
  })
 });


}

getAllCatagories() {
this.dataInfoService.findAllCatagories().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.catagories = response.content;
    console.log(this.catagories);
   },
   error => {
    this.errorMessage = error;
    console.log('Catagories Error ', error);
   }
  );
 }


onSubmit() {
 console.log('form');
}

 onResourcesChange(res) {
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Subscribe to valuechanges and within subscription use setValue / patchValue

Comment: Subscribe to valuechange and look set/patchValue what you want for next dropdown

Answer (score 0):

with an event:

```
onOptionOneChanged(event: any) {
  this.selectedOptionOne = this.optionOne.find(n => n.wathever == event.target.value);
  this.setFormControlOptionTwoValue(this.selectedOptionOne.id);
}
```

And you should write a custom form-validator for this case.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go. do you know of s simple example I can reference? or understand better?

Comment: reactive form events: [link](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/), angular.io: [link](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms/)